# Is there a way to configure samsung ultraWQHD 34 (21:9) with Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I bought a new monitor samsung ultraWQHD 34 (21:9) and I tried to configure it with my ubuntu 20.04. I tried

```
xrandr --newmode "3440x1440_60.00"  419.50  3440 3696 4064 4688  1440 1443 1453 1493 -hsync +vsync
```

and

```
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1-2 "3440x1440_60.00"
```

After that I tried

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1-2 --mode 3440x1440_60.00
```

but I get this error

```
configure crtc 1 failed
```

Here is screenshot for `xrandr -q`:

[image]
[image]

My laptop is an msi GP62 6QF leopard PRO core i7, with nvidea GeForce GTX 960M.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: This will sometimes depend on the graphics adapter. Can you [edit] your question to include: (1) the Terminal output of `xrandr -q` (2) the brand/model of your notebook (if it's a notebook) or video card (if it's a desktop). This will make it much easier to offer a possible solution 

Comment: I updated my question with few logs.